# Can "as I see fit" be replaced with "as I find fitting"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-choice, usage, word-difference

Can

> *as I see fit*

be replaced with

> *as I find fitting*

I'm trying to write a poem and that's the only word that rhymes with bidding.

Comment: No, it does not...not matter where you place it in your poetry!

Comment: I agree that "fitting" doesn't really rhyme with "bidding".  It's probably better to rewrite that stanza to find a different rhyme.  You might have better luck with the verb "bid":  *I always do as you bid* instead of *I always do your bidding*.

Comment: How about ,  ridding, skidding, kidding, forbidding. I am sure there must be more.  Check with a rhyming site.

Comment: @James - I don't think the OP means it's the **only** word in the language; I get the feeling Zack means, "the only word that fits into the train of thought I'm trying to convey AND rhymes with the previous line."

Comment: @MaulikV - Actually, these words _would_ rhyme in many American dialects. See [M-W's note on the matter](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/qa/do-americans-pronounce-t-like-d).

Answer (score 3):

In poetry you are the Czar
English rules, broken are.

Poetic licence means that you don't need to follow the same "rules". The only rule is that you write a good poem. (A rule that I have certainly broken.) What makes a "good" poem is rather beyond the scope of language learning.

I would note that "bidding" and "fitting" are not a perfect rhyme, and actually not many modern poems make any attempt at rhyme. But if you are writing a sonnet or another rhyming form, consider rephrasing the line ending "bidding"

Comment: It's also worth noting that _bidding_ and _fitting_ are pretty damn close to a perfect rhyme, especially in [American English](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/13980/why-is-t-sometimes-pronounced-like-d-in-american-english). Furthermore, it's worth noting that near rhymes (a.k.a. [slant rhymes](https://www.dailywritingtips.com/types-of-rhyme/)) have been employed by rhyming poets for centuries, from Shakespeare to Eminem.

Answer (score 1):

In general, yes. They both mean the same thing. "As I find fitting" isn't something you'd usually hear in conversation, but it fits perfectly in a poem.

Comment: Perhaps ... but "as I find fitting" is a truly awkward turn of phrase, and not one I would recommend *anyone* use.

Comment: @Andrew Agreed, I can imagine someone from the 19th century using it, but it's not something you'd use in daily life. This question is about its use in a poem though, which is somewhere it fits right in.